# Finding current state of all threads at crash time

Tags: multithreading, coredump, sigabrt

I am debugging a core file that was generated in a multi-threaded environment. The process crashed after it received a `SIGABRT`. The crash seems to be bit tricky and I want to know the execution state of all the threads when the crash happened. I guess the simple `backtrace` command just gives the execution state of the thread that was running during the crash. I want to know what command I need to use to get the backtrace for all threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you are looking for `thread apply all bt`?